# Juniper SSG20 - Bridge ADSL to ethernet interface

Tags: juniper, screenos, adsl

We're trying to reuse some leftover equipment we've got. I've got a Juniper SSG20 with 2x ADSL2/2+ mini-PIMs and we've already got a firewall solution (Which will act as the PPPoE Client) but what we need is the ADSL functionality.

Is it possible to bridge each ADSL interface onto its own and separate ethernet interface so the PPPoE client devices plugged into the appropriate interface can just work? How can I achieve this on ScreenOS 6.2?

Answer (score 1):

I played with it a bit and it looks plausible. The starting point would be switching adsl0/1 into Layer2 mode. You can accomplish this by assigning this interface to one of the V1-* zones, let's assume V1-Untrust. Then you put one or more of the ethernet interfaces in the same zone and it should make a fancy DSL modem out of you SSG-20 :-)

I haven't tested this configuration myself yet since my ADSL card is being replaced. I will able to try this in a couple of days though and will post an update.